# Is the following protocol perfect zero knowledge or computational zero knowledge?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

So I have this protocol for the hamiltonian cycle:

repeat t times:

1. Peggy chooses a random permutation $\pi$ on $V$, and computes $G_1=\pi(G)$
2. For each of the $\frac{|V|(|V|-1)}{2}$ possible edges of $G_1$ Peggy computes a different commitment and sends the commitnet to Victor. ($\forall v_1,v_2\in \pi(V)$ if $(v_1,v_2)\in \pi(E)$ then the commitment is on 1, and 0 otherwise)
3. Victor chooses a random $i\in {1,2}$ and sends it to Peggy
4. If $i=1$ the Peggy sends $\pi$ to Victor and reveals all the commitments on $G_1$. Otherwise, Peggy revelas the commitments on $|V|$ edges which form a hamiltonian cycle on $G$.
5. Victor checks Peggy's answer

So it's pretty easy to see that this is a zero knowledge protocol. How do I show if it's perfect zero knowledge or computational zero knowledge?

Answer (score 4):

This is Blum's protocol for Hamiltonicity. The answer to your question depends on the commitments. There are two possibilities:

1. **The commitments are perfectly hiding:** in this case, the proof is *perfect* zero knowledge, but is only an *argument* (meaning that soundness is computational, and so only holds against a polynomial-time cheating prover).
2. **The commitments are perfectly binding:** in this case, the proof is only *computational* zero knowledge, but is a *proof* (meaning that soundness is unconditional).

Note that no commitment scheme can be both perfectly binding and hiding. In addition, the class of perfect zero knowledge *proofs* (unconditional soundness) is contained in $AM \cap co-AM$ and so is very unlikely to contain an $NP$-complete problem.

Comment: Do you know any article/book that states that "computational zero knowledge" when commitment is perfectly binding? Thank you!